# saga getInitList() has no output in the console

Tags: redux-saga

English is not my native language, please understand!

I don't have any problem with taking pictures, but the console doesn't output anything

code：[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-glade-dp7qqv)
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in your sagas file.
you wrote:

```
yield takeEvery("GET_INIT_LIST", getInitList);
```

instead

```
yield takeEvery(GET_INIT_LIST, getInitList);
```

GET_INIT_LIST is a variable with the value "get_Init_List".

Like "get_Init_List" is different than "GET_INIT_LIST", the sagas wasn't being executed.

CodeSandbox ->https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-violet-y99pci?file=/src/store/sagas.jsx

I hope I've helped you. Have a nice day
Note: I have a github project with redux-sagas, just if you want to check it.
https://github.com/zaquielverse/react-antd